# What is the difference between "illness" and "disease"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, ambiguity

Are there any differences when those words are used? By whom they are used?

### Google n-gram

All English

[image]

English fiction:

[image]

I would guess that "illness" is rather a term which is used in spoken language and "disease" is more formal as both seem to be equally common in fiction, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Context, context, context! :-)  How do you need to use either one of those words?

Comment: Illness vs disease from a scientific perspective :http://www.bboyscience.com/disease-vs-illness/

Comment: @KristinaLopez don't need to use either of them. I am just currently a little bit ill and I am always interested in nuances of meaning of words. If you know two contexts where it is different, please let me know it. That is what I am asking for :-)

Comment: @Josh61 The two definitions make sense. Do you want to post this (with the two definitions) as an answer?

Comment: Gotcha, @moose.  If Josh61 adds his answer, I'll vote for it too.  Hope you feel better soon! :-)

Comment: A disease *causes* an illness.

Comment: Oald says they are synonyms. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/disease?q=disease

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following diagram is from the University of Ottawa, "[Society, the Individual, and Medicine (SIM) curriculum](http://www.med.uottawa.ca/SIM/welcome_e.html)" notes. The diagram illustrates the difference between *illness, disease,* and *sickness*, and it includes brief descriptions.

- *Disease* refers to the medical establishment's perspective;
- *sickness* refers to society's perspective,
- and *illness* is the way the patient perceives their condition.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The words overlap in their semantic field and can be used interchangeably, but the connotations of the two words vary.

The etymology of [illness](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=illness&allowed_in_frame=0) indicates the **malevolent nature** of the physical condition:

> "disease, sickness," 1680s, from [ill](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ill&allowed_in_frame=0) + -ness. Earlier it meant "bad
>   moral quality" (c.1500).
>
> c.1200, "morally evil" (other 13c. senses were "malevolent, hurtful,
>   unfortunate, difficult"),
>
> from Old Norse illr "ill, bad," of unknown origin.
>
> Not considered to be related to evil.
>
> Main modern sense of "sick, unhealthy, unwell" is first recorded
>   mid-15c., probably related to Old Norse idiom "it is bad to me." Slang
>   inverted sense of "very good, cool" is 1980s. As a noun, "something
>   evil," from mid-13c.

The etymology of [disease](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=disease&allowed_in_frame=0) indicates the **discomfort** and **inconvenience** of the physical condition:

> early 14c., "discomfort, inconvenience,"
>
> from Old French desaise "lack, want; discomfort, distress; trouble,
>   misfortune; disease, sickness," from des- "without, away" (see dis-) +
>   aise "ease" (see [ease](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ease&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> [c.1200, "physical comfort, undisturbed state of the body;
>   tranquility, peace of mind," from Old French aise "comfort, pleasure,
>   well-being; opportunity," which is of unknown origin, despite attempts
>   to link it to various Latin verbs; perhaps Celtic. According to OED,
>   the earliest senses in French appear to be 1. "elbow-room" (from an
>   11th century Hebrew-French glossary) and 2. "opportunity." This led
>   Sophus Bugge to suggest an origin in Vulgar Latin asa, a shortened
>   form of Latin ansa "handle," which could be used in the figurative
>   sense of "opportunity, occasion," as well as being a possible synonym
>   for "elbow," because Latin ansatus "furnished with handles" also was
>   used to mean "having the arms akimbo." OED editors add, "This is not
>   very satisfactory, but it does not appear that any equally plausible
>   alternative has yet been proposed."]
>
> Sense of "sickness, illness" in English first recorded late 14c.; the
>   word still sometimes was used in its literal sense early 17c.

By constant use the *malevolent nature* and the *discomfort* of sickness have commingled in the two words *illness* and *disease*.

According to Wikipedia:

> In many cases, terms such as *disease*, disorder, morbidity and *illness*
>   are used interchangeably.[3](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=disease&allowed_in_frame=0) There are situations however when
>   specific terms are considered preferable.
>
> **Disease**
>
> The term disease broadly refers to any condition that impairs
>   the normal functioning of the body. For this reason, diseases are
>   associated with dysfunctioning of the body's normal homeostatic
>   process.[4](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ease&allowed_in_frame=0) Commonly, the term disease is used to refer specifically
>   to infectious diseases, which are clinically evident diseases that
>   result from the presence of pathogenic microbial agents, including
>   viruses, bacteria, fungi, protozoa, multicellular organisms, and
>   aberrant proteins known as prions. An infection that does not and will
>   not produce clinically evident impairment of normal functioning, such
>   as the presence of the normal bacteria and yeasts in the gut, or of a
>   passenger virus, is not considered a disease. By contrast, an
>   infection that is asymptomatic during its incubation period, but
>   expected to produce symptoms later, is usually considered a disease.
>   Non-infectious diseases are all other diseases, including most forms
>   of cancer, heart disease, and genetic disease.
>
> **Illness**
>
> Illness and
>   sickness are generally used as synonyms for disease.[5](https://books.google.com/books?id=CQ0yAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA615&dq=%22disease%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Dk3aVIvrKaTIsQSoz4KIDg&ved=0CD8Q6wEwBzjAAg#v=onepage&q=%22disease%22&f=false) However, this
>   term is occasionally used to refer specifically to the patient's
>   personal experience of his or her disease.[6][7] In this model, it is
>   possible for a person to have a disease without being ill (to have an
>   objectively definable, but asymptomatic, medical condition), and to be
>   ill without being diseased (such as when a person perceives a normal
>   experience as a medical condition, or medicalizes a non-disease
>   situation in his or her life). Illness is often not due to infection,
>   but a collection of evolved responses—sickness behavior by the
>   body—that helps clear infection. Such aspects of illness can include
>   lethargy, depression, anorexia, sleepiness, hyperalgesia, and
>   inability to concentrate.[8][9][10]

Interestingly, the current use of the words, reverses the etymological implications with disease representing the objective nature, and illness representing the subjective experience of a malady.

etymonline.com
wikipedia.com

Answer (score 3):

The difference is less in their actual meaning and more in their purported usage.  In olden days, any ailment was a disease, but now 'known' or 'easily recoverable' ailment is considered illness and those that required severe, life-death type treatment are considered diseases.  So 'fever' is considered illness, while 'malaria' or 'jaundice' is disease.  There is no bacterial/viral distinction as well as the words are used for either.

Answer (score 1):

We see that Oald says the words illness and disease are synonyms, the University of Ottowa wants to see semantic differences, but I am sure that such distinctions are unknown to almost any speaker.
My experience is that illness is preferred in spoken language and disease is often used in texts that have medical topics such as Alzheimer's disease. But you find illness in such texts as well.